# Android application ajax call is not working after obfuscation

Tags: android, weblogic, apk, obfuscation

i have developed which is working fine at weblogic on managed server and admin server.

then i obfuscate it for security requirement by using eclipse proguard tool.
please look at project.propertis file

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../../../Desktop/XYZ/CaptureActivity
android.library.reference.2=CordovaLib
```

and proguard-project.text file

```
-keep public class * extends com.phonegap.api.Plugin
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.DroidGap
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.**
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.camera
-keep public class com.plugin.datepicker.**
-keep public class com.credentek.imagetransfer.**
-keep public class mobi.roshka.cordova.callphone.**
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.dialogs.**
-keep public class de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.**
-keep public class fr.louisbl.cordova.gpslocation.**
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.camera.**
-keep public class com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.**
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.*
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** 
{ 
    *; 
}
-keepclassmembers class * 
{
        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-keep public class org.apache.commons.** { *; }
```

after obfuscating application stop working. not even connecting to server.
actually ajax call is not working.

if anybody have some idea please share. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could post any exceptions raised when running your program.

Whenever dealing with Proguard issues, one strategy is to disable optimization and keep everything. Something like this:

```
-keep class com.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class mobi.** { *; }
-keep class fr.** { *; }
-keep class de.** { *; }

-keepattributes '*'

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
```

Make the configuration as pessimistic as possible until the configuration allows the app to work. After that, start removing packages from `-keep`.  Also, remove `-dontoptimize` and `-keepattributes`, one at a time.